# Valgrind yelling when the program works perfectly fine (C)

Tags: c, valgrind

I have a program (in its elementary stages) that is supposed to take a file from stdin, encode it and print it to stdout. It seems to work just fine, no matter what type of stdin I read in. However, Valgrind is telling me there is a problem:

```
==6508== Invalid read of size 4
==6508==    at 0x4009EC: insertObject (lzw.c:106)
==6508==    by 0x400B72: lzw_encode (lzw.c:228)
==6508==    by 0x40091D: main (lzw.c:48)
==6508==  Address 0x5203044 is 0 bytes after a block of size 65,540 alloc'd
==6508==    at 0x4C2845D: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6508==    by 0x400D51: initialize (lzw.c:305)
==6508==    by 0x400AB3: lzw_encode (lzw.c:196)
==6508==    by 0x40091D: main (lzw.c:48)
==6508==
```

Here are the relevant snippets of code:

```
int lzw_encode ()
{
    table* hashtable;
    int counter=0;
    hashtable = initialize(); //line 196
    int code = -1;
    char k;
    if ((k=getc(stdin))==EOF)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    code = k;
    while ((k=getc(stdin))!=EOF)
    {
        if (HashSearch(hashtable, code, k)!=-1)
        {   
            code=HashSearch(hashtable, code, k);
        }
        else
        {  
            putBits(12, code);

            if (hash(code, k, hashtable->size)>4340)
            {
                counter=1;
            }
            if (counter==0)
            {
                hashtable = insertObject(hashtable, code, k); //line 228
            }

            code = HashSearch(hashtable, -1, k);

        }
    }
    if (code != 0)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", code);
    }
    /*if (!fp)
    {
        printf("????\n");
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

InsertObject:

```
table *insertObject (table *h, int pref, char ch)
{
    struct node x;
    int i;
    if (ch < 0)
    {
        ch=4096-ch;
    }
    x.chr=ch;
    x.pref=pref;
    i = hash(pref, ch, h->size);
    while (h->hash[i].pref!=0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (i>4340)
    {
        return h;
    }
    h->hash[i]=x; //line 106
    return h;
}
```

Initialize:

```
table *initialize ()
{
    table *hashtable = malloc(sizeof(table)); //Line 305
    //hashtable->hash = malloc (sizeof(struct node) * 4096);
    memset(hashtable, 0, sizeof(*hashtable));
    hashtable->size=4096;
    //hashtable->hash=malloc(sizeof(table));
    for (int i=0; i<4096; i++)
    {
        hashtable->hash[i].pref=-1;
        hashtable->hash[i].before=-1;
        hashtable->hash[i].after=-1;
        hashtable->hash[i].chr=0;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        hashtable->hash[i].chr=i+128;
    }
    //printf("Initialized\n");
    return hashtable;
}
```

I've labeled the lines that are mentioned in valgrind.

EDIT:

Here are the data structures:

```
typedef struct hash_t table;

struct node {
    int pref;
    int before;
    int after;
    char chr;
};

struct hash_t {
    int size;
    struct node hash[4096];
};
```

EDIT2: Making sure that i never goes over 4096 seems to have fixed it. However, I discovered a valgrind error that I've seen before with this:

```
==20137== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==20137==    at 0x4F198B0: __write_nocancel (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==20137==    by 0x4EA8E32: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==20137==    by 0x4EAA29B: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==20137==    by 0x4EABDE6: _IO_flush_all_lockp (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==20137==    by 0x4EABF39: _IO_cleanup (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==20137==    by 0x4E6AE0A: __run_exit_handlers (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==20137==    by 0x4E6AEA4: exit (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==20137==    by 0x4E53AFB: (below main) (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==20137==  Address 0x4023002 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Based on other questions on this site, this seems to occur when a struct isn't initialized. However, I don't see any unititialized structs. Is there such a problem with this code, or should I look elsewhere in the program?

Comment: First thought: Valgrind is right. That your program currently runs does not mean that it has no errors.

Comment: and please show us line 48.

Comment: Be consistent, use `malloc(sizeof(*hashtable))`, or `calloc(3)`

Comment: Line 48 is "return lzw_encode();"

Comment: Can we also see `table` definition ?

Comment: Did you tried compiling with warnings/static analyser to see what does it says ?
The error seems to be comming from hash() ... Can it return 4096 or more by any chance ? Please check that or/and include its code

Comment: When your `i` indexes array elements from 0 to 4095, it shoudln't be allowed to be greater than 4340, should it?

Comment: Valgrind is almost always right. You're getting away with accessing the array outside its bounds most likely because malloc rounds up the size of the allocation it returns you. Since your allocation is quite large you might have a lot of slack after it. Until you link the code with a new version of libc or compile on another operating system that isn't so generous and you'll start crashing immediately. The worst that could happen with undefined behavior is happening to your program: it is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In line 106 of `insertObject`, you are attempting to read from address `hash[i]`. `hash` has size 4096, but you have checked only if `i > 4340` four lines above. During the execution of your program, `i` might have taken value between 4096 and 4340.

First block of Valgrind output informs you that you cannot read the requested four bytes from address `hash + i * sizeof(struct node)`.

Second block tells that the address you are attempting to read is just beyond the end of the allocated array of size 65,540. That is, in fact, your `h` variable passed to `insertObject`.

See e.g. http://valgrind.org/gallery/linux_mag.html for explanations of common Valgrind error reports.